# How to pass observable from params to pipe rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to write a function like this:

```
function abc(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
     pipe(arg1, arg2, arg3...); // or someSubject.pipe(arg1, arg2, arg3..)
}
```

But I always get error when build the code.
How can I do it in typescript?

Comment: What error, what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can't pipe nothing. You need a stream from the arguments.
For example:

```
of(arg1, arg2, arg3).pipe(....)
```

or

```
of([arg1, arg2, arg3]).pipe(....)
```

If you need one stream value with three arguments.